# How to understand if created window closed on JAVA

Tags: java, file, window, desktop

I am trying to check if created desktop window closed or not. Here is how I open a file with system;

```
File f = new File(url);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
```

This code is opening file in a window so my question how can I notify when this window closed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with just `Desktop.createDesktop` if you need to track the process that is opened as well. This API just does not Support this.

sample sourcecode how to do it differently, but more complex (you Need to replace it with proper Editor + path if necessary):

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe", url).start(); //assuming Windows
int result = p.waitFor(); // wait until it dies
```

Also note, that you editor of choice might need a slighlty different URL to load the file properly. (or no URL at all, just the filename)

Comment: but notpad.exe is only for notepad things, I mean, can system decide which application will use according to file extension ?